# How to get the number value from preferences editbox in android

Tags: android, preferences, editbox

I have a edit box in my preference where the user can type a number to increment a counter by but I am not sure how to get this value and use it in my main class.

in my preference I have;

```
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:key="incrementBy"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:summary="Set the incremental value of the counter"
        android:title="Increase Count by" />
```

what I want to do is, get the user input from this edit box and imply it to a variable in my main class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to get your `SharedPreferences` object, and from that retrieve the value of "incrementBy"

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(yourActivity);
String incrementBy= sharedPref.getString("incrementBy", "defaultValue");
```

Comment: but doesn't this return a string? the value should be returned in number

Comment: @ProjectX if you want to use an `EditTextPreference` you have to retrieve a `String`. You can always convert the String to a number like this: `int num = Integer.parseInt(incrementBy);`

Comment: If possible can you help me out with another problem. Is it possible to set the editbox value that I have in my preference to 1 when user presses presses a button.

Comment: Currently the value of editbox stays to what ever user inputs

Comment: @ProjectX i suppose you have to get a reference of your EditTextPreference and then use it's setText() method

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I am not sure how to get the reference for editview

Comment: @ProjectX inside of your `PreferenceActivity`    `EditTextPreference mEditTextPref =(EditTextPreference) findPreference(yourETPId);`

Comment: @ProjectX call it how you want.. the key in this case is the identifier ;) btw, we're going off topic here